# How can I disable message recommendations in Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform//sbs-gs-javascript?tabs=vscode%2Cvsc%2Cviscode%2Cvcode) to build my first bot in Microsoft Teams.
In the chat window I always get recommendations on what I can ask the bot. After a while that gets quite annoying... How can I disable that?

Here a picture of what I mean (Vorschläge means recommendations):
[message hint/recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peMZZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Command menu with a drop-down list of commands is added for your bot, to define a set of core commands that your bot can respond to. The list of commands is presented to the users in the compose message area when they are in conversation with your bot.
You can disable those commands by removing command list in manifest file of your bot app where these are defined.
[image]

If you remove any commands from your manifest, you must redeploy your app to implement the changes. In general, any changes to the manifest require you to redeploy your app.